# This Stack Exchange should have an "Insignificant Change" option under Review

Tags: feature-request

Agree or disagree?

I recently reviewed something on here, and I noticed that none of the options really fit. But the edit was so insignificant that it seemed to me that it wasn't much of an edit at all. Plus, it's more like an insertion of another person's opinion in the original. It's not really a "radical change", but it's a change to the extent that it changed the view or presuppositions of the author on the topic.

Nevertheless, I just gave a Custom reason for rejecting the edit.

Comment: I'm pretty sure "too minor" is one of the options when reviewing suggested edits...

Answer (score 5):

If it is so small and doesn't really do anything to add to the post then mark it as:

> too minor

If it changes the meaning of the post, whether the change is small or not, then mark it as:

> invalid

In the case you describe, "it's more like an insertion of another person's opinion in the original," I would go with invalid.

A custom reason is always acceptable. All that really does is give your custom message to the editor instead of one of the cookie cutter options. It really just depends on how helpful you want to be to the editor.